# Preventing workbooks from being stored in VBA Project Explorer

Tags: vba, excel, project-explorer

The code I have loops through a folder that has 100+ files (with more files being added daily) and copies files, data, etc. Every file that I loop through ends up in the VBA Project Explorer as you can see from the picture. This is really slowing down the run time of my code. **Is there any way I can prevent each workbook from being added to the Project Explorer?** Also, I haven't run my code with the optimize subroutines that I call to because I added those after running my original code (and now the editor is basically frozen). I attached my code as well as the picture of my issue below!

[image: Overloaded VBA Project Explorer]

```
Sub TransferSAPCLData_Click()

'Code Optimization
Call OptimizeCode_Begin

'Declaring and Setting Variables
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Dim MyDir As String
Dim fil As Scripting.file
Dim FolderSource As Scripting.Folder
Dim FolderPathDest As String, wbDest As Workbook, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
Dim lrDest As Long, fileDest As String, lrSource As Long
Dim CurrentFile As String
Dim fileSource As String

MyDir = "C:\Users\quirk\Desktop\Cory Project\Wave 1A Content\SAPCL Spreadsheets\SAPCL Raw Data Files"

'Defining destination characteristics
FolderPathDest = "C:\Users\quirk\Desktop\Cory Project\Wave 1A Content\Master SAPCL Folder"
fileDest = "C:\Users\quirk\Desktop\Cory Project\Wave 1A Content\Master SAPCL Folder\Function Master File.xlsm"
'Workbooks.Open Filename:=fileDest
Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook ' Workbooks("MASTER.xlsx")
Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Sheet1")


'Looping through files
Set FolderSource = fso.GetFolder(MyDir)
For Each fil In FolderSource.Files
    Debug.Print fil.Name
    CurrentFile = fil.Name
    If Not fso.FileExists(FolderPathDest & "\" & fil.Name) Then
        fso.CopyFile _
        Source:=MyDir & "\" & fil.Name _
        , Destination:=FolderPathDest & "\" & fil.Name
            fileSource = MyDir & "\" & fil.Name
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=fileSource '
            ActiveWindow.Visible = False
            Set wbSource = Workbooks(CurrentFile)
            Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
                lrSource = wsSource.Range("A" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                lrDest = wsDest.Range("A" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                wsSource.Range("A2:V" & lrSource).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range("A" & lrDest)
    End If
Next fil

'Optimize Code
Call OptimizeCode_End

End Sub
```

Comment: You're not closing the workbooks after you open them, so they remain open, and visible in the VBE editor window.  Perhaps `wbSource.Close` after your copy line?

Comment: @Fink Yep that worked! I added "Workbooks(CurrentFile).Close Savechanges:=False" and it is working now! Thank you!